# Arrays and Garbage collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Let us say I have an Array `a`, where the array is of type `T`. Would setting an element to null mark it for garbage collection.

For example, If I do `a[36] = null`, or do I need to something more, like also set fields in that object of type `T` to`null`?

Comment: BTW, you might want to edit your question to reflect that you are managing your own memory, that you get `OutOfMemoryError`s and whatever extra information you put in the comments instead of in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, it's hard to tell without the code. However, this might help:

According to Josh Bloch's *Effective Java 2nd Edition* chapter 2 item 6, you need to set the reference to `null` in order to allow it to be GC'd *if you manage your own memory*. He explains that if you don't `null` a reference it can become an *obsolete references* and these can cause an `OutOfMemoryError`.

The example he gives is the following (I'm shortening it). Consider a stack implementation where you can push and pop objects. The problem manifests in the `pop` operation:

```
public class Stack {

    private Object[] elements;
    private int size = 0;

    public Object pop() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        Object result = elements[--size];
        elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference, or you'll have a "memory leak"
        return result;
    }
```

Note that you're controlling the allocated size manually with the `size` variable and the GC can't know which elements are allocated and which are free.

Go ahead and read that section in his book for more information if you find it relevant. Your case has similarities to what I wrote, but we can't be sure without code.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, objects are stored on the heap, whereas variables/references are stored on the stack. The GC performs what is called a 'cycle', which checks which variables no longer refer to actual datatypes, as well as checking if objects are still referred to in the scope. As mario mentioned, an object will eventually be collected when nothing holds a reference to it, however in some performance/memory critical applications, setting objects to null and trying to speed up the garbage collection process has been known to provide marginal performance benefits. In this case, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: That is a simple example. In my original code, I am using Scala code in Spark, and the executor keeps on going out of memory, after one task is finished and another task is run. Basically, it seems that the memory from the previous task is not being garbage collected properly. And the culprit seems to be a variable of type StringBuffer within an object that is placed in a HashMap. Even if I set the length of the StringBuffer to 0 by using the setLength method at the end, it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you post some more code? These kinds of things tend to happen within loops that iterate through large amounts of data, where the object references are still being held and not collected.